# Java Runtime Environment 10.0+46 Crashes on macOS 10.13.4

Tags: java

While running the Python package KoNLPy (KoNLPy.tags.Twitter) inside a Django project, the JRE crashed with the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000011389ec3a, pid=12099, tid=18695
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (10.0+46) (build 10+46)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10+46, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [_jpype.cpython-35m-darwin.so+0xdc3a]  _ZN9JPJavaEnv9FindClassEPKc+0x2a
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/username/Documents/project/app/hs_err_pid12099.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Abort trap: 6
```

It only crashes most of the time when `KoNLPy.tags.Twitter` is invoked, but not all the time, which is strange.

My macOS version is 10.13.4 (High Sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module seems to be incompatible with JRE 10. I switched to version 8 and now it works fine.